# How to count ocurrences in Google Data Studio?

Tags: looker-studio

I have a table containing medical data, similar to this:

| Date/Time | Medical Record No. | Medical conditions |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 9/11/2021 9:02:04 | 1 | Condition A, Condition B, Condition C |
| 10/4/2021 9:49:11 | 2 | Condition C |
| 10/5/2021 8:58:49 | 3 |  |
| 8/16/2021 15:38:15 | 4 | Condition B, Condition D |
| 6/25/2021 10:54:18 | 2 | Condition A, Condition C |
| 8/23/2021 9:19:20 | 4 | Condition B, Condition E |
| 10/13/2021 16:40:34 | 5 | Condition A |
| 1/11/2022 15:16:06 | 2 | Condition C |
| 1/19/2022 15:29:32 | 1 | Condition C |

I need to generate a bar chart showing total ocurrences of each medical condition, limited to one per patient, as in the following hardcoded example:

| Medical condition | Occurrences (max 1 per patient) |
| --- | --- |
| Condition A | 3 |
| Condition B | 2 |
| Condition C | 2 |
| Condition D | 1 |
| Condition E | 1 |

[Expected bar chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sxPXS.png)

EDIT: Unaggregated expected result table:

| Medical Record No. | Medical Condition |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Condition A |
| 1 | Condition B |
| 1 | Condition C |
| 2 | Condition C |
| 4 | Condition B |
| 4 | Condition D |
| 2 | Condition A |
| 4 | Condition E |
| 5 | Condition A |

I was only able to achieve this resulting table using the following method:

Created one new field for each medical condition, each counting occurrences for that condition alone, like this:

Field C'A':

```
REGEXP_EXTRACT(Medical conditions,".*(Condition A).*")
```

and so on for all conditions. Then I inserted one table chart in the [report](https://datastudio.google.com/reporting/161a2949-abf2-4239-a925-9ee3e269acb8) for each condition, containing that new field and using the Medical Record No. with Count Distinct as a metric. I ended up with 5 tables smashed together that LOOKS like one table, but it's not. So I can't build the bar chart I want from that.

That solution is available in the publicly editable [report](https://datastudio.google.com/reporting/161a2949-abf2-4239-a925-9ee3e269acb8).

EDIT:

I added a publicly editable Google Data Studio Report and sample data set of the scenario, including what I need, what I get and my failed attempt, as requested in the comment!

[Data Studio report](https://datastudio.google.com/reporting/161a2949-abf2-4239-a925-9ee3e269acb8)

[Google sheet data set](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1EDJmkKTI2VV1qc8Gha3enkXHq9It_F_Q2yGsFQ2r_Dg/edit?usp=sharing)